# Adding HasRequired Configuration causes Invalid Column Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a reference table set up like this:

```
NavigationAccess:
PK FK NavigationId
PK FK UserId

Navigations:
PK NavigationId
   Name

Users
PK UserId
   Name
```

PK = PrimaryKey
FK = ForeignKey

In my Database Configuration I have the following:

```
public class NavigationAccessConfiguration
        : EntityTypeConfiguration<NavigationAccess>
    {
        public NavigationAccessConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => new { x.NavigationId, x.UserId });
            //HasRequired(x => x.Navigation).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.NavigationId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

Notice the **HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile)** is uncommented right now. When I try to run the code I get the following.

> Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'. Invalid column name
>   'UserProfile_UserId'.